# RPCRequestError while depositing WETH on aave v2 lending pool

Tags: python, testing, solidity, rpc, brownie

while I am trying to use `deposit()` function from [Aave v2 lending pool](https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPool.sol) on goerli testnet, to deposit WETH token to the lending pool, the transaction is getting reverted and the error is following:

> RPCRequestError: Accessing `TransactionReceipt.revert_msg` on a reverted transaction requires the `debug_traceTransaction` RPC endpoint, but the node client does not support it or has not made it available.

Everything works fine on the local mainnet-fork network.

Here is the relevant piece of code which I am using:

```
account = get_account()
erc20_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth_token"]
if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
    get_weth()
lending_pool = get_lending_pool_contract()
approve_erc20(
    amount, 
    lending_pool.address, 
    erc20_address, 
    account
)
print("Depositing...")
deposit_tx = lending_pool.deposit(
    erc20_address, 
    amount, 
    account.address, 
    0, 
    {"from": account, "gas_limit": 1000000, "allow_revert": True}
)
deposit_tx.wait(1)
print("Deposited!")
```

Worth mentioning that function `approve_erc20()` and related to it `approve()` transaction succeeds as it should. here is the code:

```
def approve_erc20(amount, spender, erc20_address, account):
    print("Approving ERC20 token...")
    erc20 = interface.IERC20(erc20_address)
    tx = erc20.approve(spender, amount, {"from": account})
    tx.wait(1)
    print("Approved!")
    return tx
```

- Since `Brownie`, as a default node, uses [Infura](https://app.infura.io/) for the goerli testnet I changed the host to the [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/), thought that would help but it gave me a whole different error:

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/$WEB3_ALCHEMY_PROJECT_ID

Changed it as it was before and right now I am lost.

What can be done here?

Answer (score 1):

if it works on your local env and not on server and you have used waits, maybe that waits are not enough? have you tried different amount?

also I would suggest you to post question on NFT specific stacoverflow distro

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/